# How to install ROS-fuerte with the dependency to python 2.6 when python 2.7 also exists in Ubuntu12.04?

Tags: ros, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My environment is Ubuntu-12.04, ROS-fuerte.
The default python version on Ubuntu-12.04 is python-2.7. I firstly installed ROS-fuerte depending on python-2.7.
But I would like to use ROS with other software that developed by Python-2.6. So I installed python-2.6, and make it default in my system. And then I re-installed the ROS-fuerte (want to change its dependency) using "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full". But I found that the ROS still depends on python-2.7(the python library under ROS is /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7).
What should I do to make ROS work with python-2.6?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59363/how-to-install-ros-fuerte-with-the-dependency-to-python-2.6-when-python-2.7-also-exists-in-ubuntu12.04?/) by [Amigoshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4540/amigoshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-18**:
Interestingly, I just found that python version supported in `fuerte` is 2.6, which is not supported on Precise. [I opened a question](http://answers.ros.org/question/61099/supported-python-in-fuerte-is-26-though-not-supported-on-precise/).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-07**:
Are you sure the other software will not work with Python 2.7? There are not many differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS will work with python 2.6, but the packaged binaries are packaged against the default system python.  If you pull the packages you need from source they should work.  Repackaging will be a very big pain.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2